# looking for filename having timestamp as today -1

Tags: ruby, file, ftp, find, timestamp

```
ftp.gettextfile('ReceiveLog_ABC-4444_yyyymmdd.log','upsmi.csv')
```

Today is 20161103.

How can I get `ReceiveLog_ABC-4444_20161102.log`?

I want to know if date were 20161201, how to look for 20161130 file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Date library to handle this:

```
require 'date'

date_format = '%Y%m%d'
date = Date.parse('20161103', date_format)
# => #<Date: 2016-11-03 ((2457696j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

previous_date = date - 1
# => #<Date: 2016-11-02 ((2457695j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

previous_date.strftime(format)
# => "20161102"
```

This handles incrementing and decrementing to properly account for the lengths of the months and the start/end of the year.